# Python - existing "standard library" test cases for collections.abc subclasses

Tags: python-3.x

I've written a BinarySearchTree subclass of `collections.abc.MutableMapping`.

Within either the (C) Python code base or as a library, is there a standard set of test cases I can simply rerun on my subclass? I'd like to avoid having to write a full suite of tests if there's already an industrial-strength set to test `dict`.